# Vector in c++ printing input out repetitively

Tags: c++

My code is supposed to take input from the user terminated by '|' and print out a vector using a while-loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    int number;
    cout<<"Enter some numbers: ";
    while(cin>>number) 
    {
        numbers.push_back(number);
        for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++)
            {
                cout<<numbers[i]<<" ";
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, say I enter the values: `1 2 3 4 |`

The output is: `1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4`

Please help

Comment: Didn't someone just ask this exact question for Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your for loop outside the while loop. Right now for every input value it will print out the entire vector. This will print only when you are done with inputting numbers for your program.

```
while(cin>>number) 
{
    numbers.push_back(number);
}
for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++)
{
    cout<<numbers[i]<<" ";
}
return 0;
```